# logging.config.fileConfig : SyntaxError: (unicode error)

Tags: logging, unicode, syntax-error, config, python-3.7

When I run the following **Python 3** code in **CMD** or **Powershell** :

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time

logging.config.fileConfig('log_config.ini',
                          defaults={'logfilename': time.strftime(str(__file__.split(".")[0].split("/")[-1]) + "_%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.log", time.localtime())})
```

I get the following error :

```bsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    defaults={'logfilename': time.strftime(str(__file__.split(".")[0].split("/")[-1]) + "_%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.log", time.localtime())})
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 79, in fileConfig
    handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 142, in _install_handlers
    args = eval(args, vars(logging))
  File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-17: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

However, I don't meet this problem with PyCharm.

This is my log configuration file :

```
# Configuration
[logger_root]
level = DEBUG
handlers = consoleHandler, fileHandler

# ========================================= DECLARATIONS
[loggers]
keys = root

[handlers]
keys = consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys = simpleFormatter

# ========================================= DEFINITION DES HANDLERS

# Le handler par défaut écrit dans la console...
[handler_consoleHandler]
class = StreamHandler
level = DEBUG
formatter = simpleFormatter
args = (sys.stdout,)

# ...et un handler plus axé production qui écrit dans un fichier
[handler_fileHandler]
class = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level = INFO
formatter = simpleFormatter
args = ('logs/%(logfilename)s', 'D', 1, 30)

# ========================================= DEFINITION DES FORMATTERS

# Le formatter utilisé de façon standard
[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format = [%(asctime)s] - [%(levelname)s] - [%(name)s] - [%(filename)s:%(lineno)s] - %(message)s
```

If someone has encountered the same problem with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PyCharm, `__file__` returns a string with "/".

While in CMD and powershell, `__file__` returns a string with "\".

We have just to add `.replace("\\", "/")` after `__file__` :

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time

logging.config.fileConfig('log_config.ini',
                          defaults={'logfilename': time.strftime(str(__file__.replace("\\", "/").split(".")[0].split("/")[-1]) + "_%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.log", time.localtime())})
```